# How do I figure out which library is causing ldconfig to segfault?

Tags: compiling, libraries, debugging, derivatives

I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 distro for NanoPi Neo 2 and found something interesting.

Running ldconfig.real -i (ignoring auxiliary cache) ought to rebuild the library cache. Instead, the binary generates a segmentation fault.

This error is reproducible on the Xenial image but does not occur with the Armbian 5.34 (4.13 kernel) or the Armbian 5.35 (3.4 kernel) distro images.

All images were tested as they are, without updates or modifications.

I think the problem may lie in libc, but I'm not sure how to find out.

Any suggestions...? I’m considering recompiling all the libraries (one by one) with apt-src to see which one is broken.

Comment: Read `man strace`, and do something like `strace -e trace=open,read ldconfig.real -i` to see which file it's reading at the crash.

Comment: Tried verbose mode? `ldconfig.real -iv`?